# Exact difference between Kafka and AsyncApi

Tags: apache-kafka, asyncapi

I am new in Kafka and want to understand what is the difference between AsyncAPI and Kafka itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AsyncAPI is a specification, bringing async semantics to (synchronous) OpenAPI models.

Apache Kafka is a distributed event platform. It has a TCP protocol, but otherwise no external "API specification". All events sent to Kafka are binary, not types like [cloudevents](/questions/tagged/cloudevents).

You can implement the AsyncAPI around Apache Kafka...

As per docs

> The AsyncAPI Specification is a project used to describe and document message-driven APIs in a machine-readable format. It’s protocol-agnostic, so you can use it for APIs **that work over any protocol** (e.g., AMQP, MQTT, WebSockets, ***Kafka***, STOMP, HTTP, Mercure, etc).